# PHP PDO Add filter to all queries

Tags: php, mysql, pdo, filter

Is there a way, using JUST PHP PDO (No ORMs) to globally filter all fetch/insert/update/delete operations.

One example is a tenant field (in a multitenant db). I would like to globally add this type of filter to all operations:

tenant = companyA

Once again. NO ORMs, I already know how to do it with SQL Alquemy, Laravel's eloquent and Doctrine. I now want to know if it's possible just with PDO.

Comment: Are you basically wanting to automatically add `WHERE tenant= 'companyA'` to all queries? You could probably extend `PDO` and override some methods, use an SQL parser or something and modify the query to your liking.

Comment: Yea, that's my idea, but what do I have to override/extend? :)

Comment: @MauricioLopez you only need to extend the PDO and write your own functions, like find(), findAll(), persist()...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create a class extending `PDO` like

`class DB extends PDO {...`

Normally i override the `__construct()` method to get database credentials inside any document and connect to database, don't forget to call on bottom of this method the parent constructor `parent::__construct()`...

Then you can use your own methods

```
public function find($params) {
     ...
     $stmt = $this->prepare('')...

     $rows = $stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)...
}
```

Inside your own method you can apply your filters...