# Multitenant app with single database

Tags: laravel, laravel-5.1

I'm developing a multitenant application using Laravel. I've read different blogs, posts, sites for this and I decided to do it with a single database.

So, I know that I only need to filter every query with the tenant_id and that's it! But if I do it from every query, probably someday there'll be an error and I don't want to cause any information security issue for my tenants.

I read, probably, an old article for it, [culttt.com/2014/03/31/multi-tenancy-laravel-4](http://culttt.com/2014/03/31/multi-tenancy-laravel-4), and I found many concepts that I still don't understand because I'm new to Laravel.

Is this approach still the best for do it? Or has Laravel now its own solution to do it?

I like something similar to this: [stackoverflow.com/questions/33219951/php-pdo-add-filter-to-all-queries](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33219951/php-pdo-add-filter-to-all-querie) but from Eloquent. How can I do this?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

If I were you I would not go this way. I would create separate database for each client/each app - it's much safer solution and in addition in case you will need create Database backups or restore some client data it will be much simpler to do that than dealing with huge database when you have all your clients.

Comment: Thanks @marcin-nabialek Actually I was working with that approach but tenant databases probably will be 50MB each one and by this moment, I'll not include customized add-ons. So, I decided the other approach. Do you have any experience on this approach?